# Select One Menu - p:ajax Event is not called

Tags: jsf, primefaces

If i do a Change in the selectOneMenu the handleFactoryEvent Method is called in my Bean(see p:ajax Tag). That function!

But if i do a Change to the selectItem "bitte auswählen" the handleFactoryEvent is not called. What should i do that the handleFactoryEvent is also called, if i Change the selectOneMenu to "bitte auswählen".

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="factory" style="width:151px"
value="#{measurementTemplateViewActions.actualMeasurementTemplate.factory}"
filter="true" filterMatchMode="contains" >
<f:converter binding="#{factoryConverter}" />
<f:selectItem itemValue="#{null}" itemLabel="bitte auswählen" noSelectionOption="true"/>
<f:selectItems
    value="#{factoryDataActions.getAllFactorysForProject()}"
    var="factory"
    itemLabel="#{factory.factoryName} 
                    / #{factory.inventarnumber} / #{factory.cycle} " />
<p:ajax
    listener="#{measurementTemplateViewActions.handleFactoryEvent}"
    update="@form"/>

</p:selectOneMenu>
```

Comment: Any errors? jsf messages? maybe the converter blocks things. Does it work using a plain jsf `h:selectOneMenu`? (and f:ajax)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [f:ajax not working when dropdown return null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26458282/fajax-not-working-when-dropdown-return-null)

Comment: Can you provide code for `factoryConverter` and `handleFactoryEvent()`?